# 2004 Saturn Ion Quick Connect from OEM

Tags: cooling-system, radiator, saturn

I've purchased a new radiator for 2004 Saturn ION and it came with quick connect fittings. My oil cooler lines require thread connect. Is there a way to switch them to quick connect, or is there a fitting that can be used with my lines?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a very similar situation right now.
What did you end up doing?

Comment: I took off a radiator from the same year saturn which had the appropriate fittings